# create SPFx web part which consume 2 RESt APIs and show their results

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sharepoint-2010, spfx

We want to create a custom SPFx web part which consume those 2 RESt API:-

1. One to get a list of all reviews from Google:- https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews
2. The other is to get details about each review:- https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#get_a_specific_review

Then we want to show the latest 5 reviews which have rating 4 or more our of 5.

So can anyone advice how we can create such an SPFX web part? and is there an SPFx web part which do similar thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can build a SPFX solution (as an example look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). Basically, you have a React application where you can make 2 calls to the endpoints (you can use axios) and render the results.